# symfony constraints, array field either not exist or string

Tags: php, symfony

for example I have array like this:

```
[
   'id' => 1,
   'name' => 'some name',
]
```

but also it can be without name at all, like this:

```
[
   'id' => 1,
]
```

how can I validate it with a Symfony constraints?

I tried like this:

```
$this->validator->validate($data, new Assert\Collection([
  'fields => [
     'id' => [
         new Assert\Required(),
         new Assert\Type(['type' => 'integer']),
     ],
     'name' => [
         new Assert\Optional(),
         new Assert\Type(['type' => 'integer']),
     ],
  ]
]));
```

and like this:

```
$this->validator->validate($data, new Assert\Collection([
  'fields => [
     'id' => [
         new Assert\Optional(),
         new Assert\Type(['type' => 'integer']),
     ],
     'name' => new Assert\AtLeastOneOf([
                    new Assert\Optional(),
                    new Assert\Type(['type' => 'string']),
                ]),
  ]
]));
```

and it's not working, when field not exist I'm getting error that field is missing.

Thanks in advice!

Comment: You can set the option `allowMissingFields` on your Collection-constraint. See: https://symfony.com/index.php/doc/current/reference/constraints/Collection.html#allowmissingfields. Would you like an example as answer?

Comment: well, in the real array I have more fields, and not all of them can be treated as 'allow missing'. If I set `allowMissingFields` to `true` and id will be missing it, will treat it as a valid right? but Id should not be missing

Comment: yeah, I just tried with `allowMissingFields` and without `id` and even if I have a `Required` rule for id, it still passing validation, so `allowMissingFields` not working

Comment: You could write a separate, dedicated RequiredFields-constraint that checks whether the required fields are set and your collection only applies the the constraints for each field, if the field exists. I guess this is what you already try do with Optional/Required, but instead of applying the constraint on the field, you should check the array itself

Comment: not sure I'm following, can you show an example, please

Comment: You could also kind of simulate this by having one `@Collection`-constraint for all required fields with `allowExtraFields` set to true and a second `@Collection`-constraint for your optional constraints with `allowMissingFields` set to true

Comment: What about using `Callback` for custom validation? https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html

Comment: well, `Callback` also not working :( if field does not exist, callback rule simply omitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Version 1 using only constraints provided by Symfony:**

```php
$this->validator->validate($data, [
    # Checks only the required fields on your collection
    new Assert\Collection([
        'fields => [
            'id' => [
                new Assert\Type(['type' => 'integer']),
            ],
        ],
        'allowExtraFields' => true, // This will allow for additional optional fields
        'allowMissingFields => false, // This makes sure that all fields described here are mandatory
    ]),
    # Checks only the optional fields on your collection
    new Assert\Collection([
        'fields => [
            'name' => [
                new Assert\Type(['type' => 'string']),
            ],
        ],
        'allowExtraFields' => true, // This will allow for additional required fields
        'allowMissingFields => true,
    ])
]);
```

This will allow submitting `['id' => ?]` and `['id' => ?, 'name' => ?]`, but not `['name' => ?]`.

You can also work with different groups, but then you have to specify which group you are checking for when you call `validate()`, so that is probably not as helpful.

**Version 2 your own custom constraint:**

```php
$this->validator->validate($data, [
    @RequiredFields(['id']),
    @Assert\Collection(...like in your example...)
]);
```

The constraint itself could then look something like:

```
class RequiredFieldsValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if (!$constraint instanceof RequiredFieldsConstraint) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($constraint, ContainsAlphanumeric::class);
        }
        if ($value === null) {
            return;
        }
        if (!is_array($value)) {
            throw new UnexpectedValueException($value, 'array');
        }

        foreach ($requiredField in $constraint->fields) {
            if (!array_key_exists($requiredField, $value)) {
                // build constraint error for this field
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The constraint itself can then look similar to [Collection](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.x/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraints/Collection.php).